# Minimizing a function with scipy.minimize

Tags: python, scipy

I'm totally new to scipy.

Two variables (x1 and x2) are tested inside a pandas dataframe and produces result p.

I am looking to find x1 and x2 such that p is minimized.

The bounds on x1 and x2 are the same (-4,4)

Here is my current code

```
def objective(x):

    x1 = x[0]
    x2 = x[1]
    df.loc[(df['H3'] <= x1) & (df['A3'] >= x2), 'BH'] = 'Y'
    df.loc[(df['H3'] > x1) | (df['A3'] < x2), 'BH'] = 'N'
    df.loc[(df['BH'] == 'Y') & (df['SPR'] == 'A'), 'PH'] = -1
    df.loc[(df['BH'] == 'Y') & (df['SPR'] == 'H'), 'PH'] = df['SPC'] - 1
    df.loc[df['BH'] == 'N','PH'] = 0
    df.loc[df['SPR'] == 'D','PH'] = 0

    p = df['PH'].sum()

    return p

x0 = [0,0]

b1 = (-4,4)
b2 = (-4,4)
bnds= (b1,b2)

sol = minimize (objective,x0,method='SLSQP',bounds=bnds)
```

However, this only seems to return the answer for x1 = 0 and x2 = 0 and does not try any other values within the bounds...

What am I missing here?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If I'm interpreting your objective function correctly, it seems to be looking for specific characters in an array of characters. This makes your function non differentiable. Using a gradient based solver like SLSQP is therefore not going to work, as the gradient will be zero everywhere. 
Try using differential evolution or nelder mead instead. Those are the gradient-free algs in scipy optimize. 
Also, if x are discrete valued, and can only be within -4,4, then there are only 81 possible values and this could also be easily solved using brute force.